# pthread_tryjoin_np? Is there a Windows version of it?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, pthreads

pthread_tryjoin_np is non portable. Is there a Windows version of it of some kind? To create a thread but without blocking?

Comment: Note that pthread_tryjoin_np have nothing to do with creating a thread.

Comment: POSIX threads are generally not portable beyond POSIX platforms anyway, even if there are implementations of it in e.g. Windows. You might want to use [the native WIN32 thread functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows instead?

Answer (score 1):

In windows [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you a HANDLE which you can wait for to learn when the thread exits - which is similar to pthread_tryjoin on posix platforms.

To wait with a timeout, or poll for exit of the thread, which is what pthread_tryjoin_np usually does (_np stands for non-portable, so there might be various variation of that function) you use [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the HANDLE of the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Althought not in the current official realease (2.9.1 as of May 27th 2012) `pthread_tryjoin()` is in the current trunk on https://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/pthreads/?cvsroot=pthreads-win32

Please see the ChangeLog here: https://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/pthreads/ChangeLog?rev=1.370&content-type=text/plain&cvsroot=pthreads-win32

You can pull the sources using CVS like this

```
cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@sourceware.org:/cvs/pthreads-win32 checkout pthreads
```

They should build using VC Express or MinGW gcc.